# How to select collection with id in array embed from other collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection: photos and users. I want select list user with user_id in likes array embed from photos collection.

photos:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "title": "Title",
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("")
        }
    ],
}
```

users:

```
{
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "name": "Name1",
    "avatar": "Path1",
    },

    {
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "name": "Name2",
    "avatar": "Path2",
    },
}
```

Output with paging:

```
{
        {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""),
        "name": "Name1",
        "avatar": "Path1",
        },

        {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""),
        "name": "Name2",
        "avatar": "Path2",
        },
    }
```

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma I have added the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you...

```
db.getCollection('photos').aggregate([{ $lookup:
   {
     from: "users",
     localField: "likes.user_id",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "likes"
   }
```

}
])

The output is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"title" : "Title",
"likes" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""),
        "name" : "Name1",
        "avatar" : "Path1"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(""),
        "name" : "Name2",
        "avatar" : "Path2"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is very helpful to me. But I have separated this function. I need to output as on posts(Edited).